# SQL Get supplier by latest date

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a table where it has supplier, product and the date,

Right now my query returns suppliers, products and the latest date for each

```
    SELECT 
        Supplier,
        Product,
        MAX(LastDate)
    FROM 
        Products
    WHERE Supplier IN (''J1006962'', ''00000820'') 
    AND Product = ''M131200''       
    GROUP BY 
        Supplier,
        Product
```

this returns

```
Supplier     Product    LastDate
00000820     M131200    1190506
J1006962     M131200    1180516
```

the outcome should be

```
Supplier     Product    LastDate
00000820     M131200    1190506
```

the date is in db2 format since it's a linked server

Comment: select top 1? Order by LastDate DESC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 1 product then dont need `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Supplier,
    Product,
    LastDate
FROM 
    Products
WHERE Supplier IN ('J1006962', '00000820') 
AND Product = ''M131200''       
ORDER BY LastDate DESC;
```

If want the last supplier for each product use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Supplier,
        Product,
        LastDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY LastDate DESC) as rn
    FROM 
        Products
    WHERE Supplier IN ('J1006962', '00000820') 
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to do this:

```
SELECT 
    Supplier,
    Product,
    MAX(LastDate)
FROM 
    Products
WHERE Supplier IN (''J1006962'', ''00000820'') 
AND Product = ''M131200''       
GROUP BY 
    Supplier,
    Product
ORDER BY(LastDate);
```

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: this gives error The statement contains column name LastDate and an aggregate function in the SELECT clause..

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `SELECT TOP 1` and order it:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    Supplier,
    Product,
    MAX(LastDate)
FROM 
    Products
WHERE Supplier IN (''J1006962'', ''00000820'') 
AND Product = ''M131200''       
GROUP BY 
    Supplier,
    Product
ORDER BY LastDate DESC
```